# vscode, emacs navigation shortcuts in all input fields

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to set shortcuts(ctrl+b, ctrl+f) for commands(cursorLeft, cursorRight) in all input fields( command palette, search field ...),

it works in main editor field but not in any other input fields.